# How do I locate where my variables are multi-driven?

Tags: verilog

I am getting a multi-driven error. I am not sure how to fix this. I am trying to write a code for a simple calculator. I think it is a problem with using combinations and clock design in one module.

When I remove the output logic, the implementation runs successfully; but when I add the output logic, I get the multi-driven error.  Verilog shows that the code is multi-driven in multiple areas.

Verilog says that the regs ones,tens,hundreds,thousands,and neg are mutli driven.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module project2(w,clock,reset,error,Z);
input [3:0] w;
output  error;
input clock,reset;
wire  [16:0] answer;
reg [3:0]thousands,hundreds,tens,ones,operand;
reg [3:0]thousandsB,hundredsB,tensB,onesB;
reg [1:0] Operator;
 reg  errordisp,neg,negB;
wire [15:0]A2,B2,Z1,Result;
 reg [16:0] A,B;

 output reg [19:0]Z;   
 reg [3:0] next,present;

parameter S0 = 4'b0000, S1 = 4'b0001, S2 = 4'b0010, S3 = 4'b0011, S4 = 4'b0100, S5 = 4'b0101, S6 = 4'b0110, S7 = 4'b0111, S8 = 4'b1000, S9 = 4'b1001, S10 = 4'b1010,
sign = 4'b1111, blk = 4'b1110, add = 4'b1010, sub = 4'b1011, mult = 4'b1100, div = 4'b1101, enter = 4'b1110;

// OUTPUT LOGIC
always @(w,present)
       case( present)
     S0: Z = {blk,blk,blk,blk,4'b0};

     S1: if (neg==1) Z = {blk,blk,blk,sign,ones}; 
     else Z = {blk,blk,blk,blk,ones};

     S2: if (neg==1) Z = {blk,blk,sign,tens,ones}; 
     else Z = {blk,blk,blk,tens,ones};

     S3: if (neg==1) Z = {blk,sign,hundreds,tens,ones}; 
     else Z = {blk,blk,hundreds,tens,ones};

     S4: if (neg==1) Z = {sign,thousands,hundreds,tens,ones}; 
     else Z = {blk,thousands,hundreds,tens,ones};         

     S5:begin 
     if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8] == 0)&&(A[7:4] == 0)&&( A[3:0]!= 0))

        Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,A[3:0]};

                                      else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[7:4] == 0)&&( A[3:0]!= 0)) 
                                      Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,sign,A[3:0]};

                                      else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8] == 0)&&(A[3:0] != 0))
                                      Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                      else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[3:0] != 0))
                                      Z  =  {blk,blk,sign,A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                      else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  != 0))
                                      Z  =  {blk,blk,A[11:8],A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                      else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8] != 0))
                                          Z  =  {blk,sign,A[11:8],A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                      else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] != 0))
                                      Z  =  {sign,A[15:12],A[11:8],A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                      else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] != 0))
                                          Z  =  {blk,A[15:12],A[11:8],A[7:4],A[3:0]};       

                                     else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[7:4] != 0)&&( A[3:0]== 0)) 
                                          Z  =  {blk,blk,sign,A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                     else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[7:4] != 0)&&( A[3:0]== 0)) 
                                          Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,A[7:4],A[3:0]};                                         

                                    else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[7:4] == 0)&&( A[3:0]== 0)) 
                                      Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,4'b0};  

                                      else
                                      Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,blk};
                                      end
      S6:begin

                 if(negB == 1'b0)
                 Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,onesB};
                 else if(negB == 1'b1)
                     Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,sign,onesB};
                 else    

                 Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,onesB}; 
                 end
                 //end
                 S7:begin
                 if((negB == 1'b1)&&( tensB != 0))
                 Z  =  {blk,blk,sign,tensB,onesB};

                 else if ((negB == 1'b0)&&( tensB != 0))
                 Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,tensB,onesB};
                 else
                     Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,onesB};
                 end

                 S8:begin
                 if(negB == 1'b1)
                 Z  =  {blk,sign,hundredsB,tensB,onesB};
                 else
                 Z  =  {blk,blk,hundredsB,tensB,onesB}; 
                 end

                 S9:begin
                 if(negB == 1'b1)
                 Z  =  {sign,thousandsB,hundredsB,tensB,onesB};
                 else
                Z  =  {blk,thousandsB,hundredsB,tensB,onesB}; 
                 end


               S10:begin
                                 if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8] == 0)&&(A[7:4] == 0)&&( A[3:0]!= 0))

                                 Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,A[3:0]};

                                 else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[7:4] == 0)&&( A[3:0]!= 0)) 
                                 Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,sign,A[3:0]};

                                 else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8] == 0)&&(A[3:0] != 0))
                                 Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                 else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[3:0] != 0))
                                 Z  =  {blk,blk,sign,A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                 else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  != 0))
                                 Z  =  {blk,blk,A[11:8],A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                 else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8] != 0))
                                     Z  =  {blk,sign,A[11:8],A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                 else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] != 0))
                                 Z  =  {sign,A[15:12],A[11:8],A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                 else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] != 0))
                                     Z  =  {blk,A[15:12],A[11:8],A[7:4],A[3:0]};       

                                else if ((A[16] == 1'b1)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[7:4] != 0)&&( A[3:0]== 0)) 
                                     Z  =  {blk,blk,sign,A[7:4],A[3:0]};

                                else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[7:4] != 0)&&( A[3:0]== 0)) 
                                     Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,A[7:4],A[3:0]};                                         

                               else if ((A[16] == 1'b0)&&(A[15:12] == 0)&&(A[11:8]  == 0)&&(A[7:4] == 0)&&( A[3:0]== 0)) 
                                 Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,4'b0};  

                                 else
                                 Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,blk};
                                 end


                 default: 
                 begin Z  =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,blk};
                            {neg,thousands,hundreds,tens,ones} =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,4'b0};     
                     end
                 endcase        



// NEXT STATE LOGIC
initial present = 0;

always@(*)
    begin 
    case(present)

S0: if (( w >= 1) && ( w <=9)) next = S1;

              else if (( w == add) || ( w == sub) || ( w == mult) || (w == div)) next = S5;

                  else if ( w == sign) next = S0;

                       else if ( w == 0) next = S0;

                           else next = S0;    

S1: if ((w >= 0) && (w <= 9 )) next = S2; 

              else if ( w == enter) next = S1; 

                  else if ( w==sign) next = S1;

                       else if(( w == add) || ( w == sub) || ( w == mult) || (w == div)) next = S5;

                             else next = S1;     

S2: if ((w >= 0) && (w <= 9 )) next = S3; 

              else if ( w == enter) next = S2; 

                  else if ( w==sign) next = S2;

                          else next = S5;          

S3: if ((w >= 0) && (w <= 9 )) next = S4; 

              else if ( w == enter) next = 3; 

                  else if ( w==sign) next = S3;

                      else next = S5;

S4: if (( w == add) || ( w == sub) || ( w == mult) || (w == div)) next = S5;

               else if ((w == sign)) next = S4; 

                   else if ((w == enter)) next = S4;

                        else next = S4; 

S5: if (( w == add) || ( w == sub) || ( w == mult) || (w == div)) next = S5;

               else if ((w >= 0) && (w <= 9 )) next = S6;

                  else if (( w == enter)) next = S5;

                        else next = S5;

S6: if (( w >= add) &&(w <= div)) next = S5;    

              else if ((w >= 0) && (w <= 9 )) next = S7; 

                  else if ((w == sign)) next = S6;

                        else if ((w == enter)) next = S10;

                           else next = S6;
S7: if (( w == add) || ( w == sub) || ( w == mult) || (w == div)) next = S5;    

               else if ((w >= 0) && (w <= 9 )) next = S8;

                   else if ((w == sign)) next = S7;

                        else if ((w == enter)) next = S10;

                            else next = S7;

S8: if (( w == add) || ( w == sub) || ( w == mult) || (w == div)) next = S5;

                else if ((w >= 0) && (w <= 9 )) next = S9;  

                      else if ((w == sign)) next = S8;

                          else if ((w == enter)) next = S10;

                              else next = S8;

S9: if (( w >= 0)&&( w <= 9)) next = S10;

           else if (( w == add) || ( w == sub) || ( w == mult) || (w == div)) next = S5; 

               else if ((w == sign)) next = S9;

                       else if ((w == enter)) next = S10;

                              else next = S9;

S10: if ((w >= 1) && (w <= 9 )) next = S0;

              else if (( w == add) || ( w == sub) || ( w == mult) || (w == div)) next = S10;

                      else if (w == 0)  next = S0;

                           else  if ((w >= 1) && (w <= 9 )&&( error == 1'b1)) next = S10;

                                   else next = S10;  

  default: next = S0;      
  endcase
  end

// STATE TRANSITION FOR CONTROL LOGIC 

always@(posedge clock or posedge reset)
   if (reset)
       present <= S0;
   else 
       present  <= next;  

// REGISTER TRANFER OPERATIONS
always@(posedge clock or posedge reset)
   if (reset)
       begin  
            errordisp <= 0;
            ones <= 4'b0;
            tens  <= 4'b0;
            hundreds <= 4'b0;
            thousands <= 4'b0;
            neg <= 0;
            onesB <= 4'b0;
            tensB  <= 4'b0;
            hundredsB <= 4'b0;
            thousandsB <= 4'b0;
            negB <= 0;
       end
   else 

   case(present)

       S0:begin

          if ((w<=4'b1001) && (w>4'b0000))
             begin
                   tens <= 4'b0;
                   hundreds <=4'b0;
                   thousands <= 4'b0;
                   neg <= 1'b0;
                   ones <= w;
                A <= {neg,4'b0,4'b0,4'b0,ones};
         end
          else if ((w >= add) && ( w <= div))

              begin
                   operand <= w;  
                   ones <= 4'd0;
                   A <= {neg,4'b0,4'b0,4'b0,4'd0};                                             
                    end

          end
       S1: begin 
                   if ((w<=4'b1001) && (w>=4'b0000))
                       begin

                               tens <= ones;
                               ones <= w;
                               A <= {neg,4'b0,4'b0,tens,ones}; 
                       end

                   else if (w==4'b1111)                     
                          begin                           
                             neg <= ~neg;
                                if (neg == 1)                                 
                                    begin                                  
                                    tens <= sign ;                                
                               end
               end 

                   else if ((w >= add) && ( w <= div))
                          begin
                           A <= {neg,4'b0,4'b0,4'b0,ones};
                          operand <= w;
                          end
                   else
                       begin
                   tens <= 4'b0;
                   ones <= ones;

                       end                  
           end 
       S2: begin 
                   if ((w<=4'b1001) && (w>=4'b0000))
                   begin
                     A <= {neg,4'b0,hundreds,tens,ones};
                     hundreds <= tens;
                     tens <= ones;
                     ones <= w;
                    end

             else if (w==4'b1111)
                     begin
                       neg <= ~neg;
                      if (neg ==1) 
                       begin
                      hundreds <= sign;

                    end 
                end
              else if ((w >= add) && ( w <= div))
                             begin
                                      operand <= w;                      
                                      A <= {neg,4'b0,4'b0,tens,ones}; 
                               end  
                       end

       S3: begin 
                   if  ((w<=4'b1001) && (w>=4'b0000))
                      begin
                      A <= {neg,thousands,hundreds,tens,ones};
                      thousands <= hundreds;
                      hundreds <= tens;
                      tens <= ones;
                      ones <= w;
                      end

             else if (w==4'b1111)
                    begin
                       neg <=~neg;
                       if (neg ==1)                    
                      thousands <= sign;

                  end 
              else if ((w >= add) && ( w <= div))
                    begin
                     operand <= w;                      
                     A <= {neg,4'b0,hundreds,tens,ones}; 
                       end  

                 end                  

          S4: begin            

                     if (w==4'b1111)
                                       begin
                                           neg <= ~neg;
                                           if (neg == 1)
                                           neg <= sign;

                                                    end 

                       else if ((w >= add) && ( w <= div))

                        begin

                          operand <= w;  
                          A <= {neg,thousands,hundreds,tens,ones};

                            end    

                end

           S5:        
                 if ((w >= add) && ( w <= div))              

                        begin
                          A <= answer; operand <= w;

                        end

                 else if (( w >= 1)&&( w <= 9))

                         begin

                            tensB <= 4'b0;
                            hundredsB <= 4'b0;
                            thousandsB <= 4'b0;
                            onesB <= w;
                            B <= {negB,4'b0,4'b0,4'b0,onesB};
                          end
                 else if ( w == 4'b1111)
                           negB <= ~negB;

            S6:
               if (( w >= 0)&&( w <= 9))
                   begin 
                       onesB <= w;
                       tensB <= onesB;
                       B <= {negB,4'b0,4'b0,tensB,onesB};
                   end    

               else if (w == 4'b1111)
                     begin                           
                         negB <= ~negB;
                         if (neg == 1)                                                                                        
                                   tensB <= sign ;
                                            end
               else if (( w >= add )&&( w <= div) &&( error == 1'b0))
                       begin
                           operand <= w; A <= answer;                    
                               end 

              else if (( w >= add )&&( w <= div) &&( error == 1'b1))     
                     errordisp <= 1'b1;

              else if (( w == enter)&&( error == 1'b0))       
                    begin
                           A <= answer; operand <= w;
                     end

             else if (( w == enter)&&( error == 1'b1)) 

                   errordisp <= 1'b1;
       S7:
                              if (( w >= 0)&&( w <= 9))
                                  begin 

                                      hundredsB <= tensB;
                                      onesB <= w;
                                      tensB <= onesB;
                                      B <= {negB,4'b0,hundredsB,tensB,onesB};
                                  end    

                              else if (w == 4'b1111)
                                    begin                           
                                        negB <= ~negB;
                                        if (neg == 1)                                                                                        
                                                  hundredsB <= sign ;
                                                           end
                              else if (( w >= add )&&( w <= div) &&( error == 1'b0))
                                      begin
                                          operand <= w; A <= answer;                    
                                                tens <= answer[7:4];
                                                                 hundreds <= answer[11:8];
                                                                 thousands <= answer[15:12];
                                                                 ones <= answer[3:0];
                                              end 

                             else if (( w >= add )&&( w <= div) &&( error == 1'b1))     

                                    errordisp <= 1'b1; 

                             else if (( w == enter)&&( error == 1'b0))       
                                   begin
                                          A <= answer; operand <= w;
                                    end

                            else if (( w == enter)&&( error == 1'b1)) 

                                  errordisp <= 1'b1;                 
   S8:
                             if (( w >= 0)&&( w <= 9))
                             begin 
                               neg <= sign;
                               thousandsB <= hundredsB;
                               hundreds <= tensB;
                               onesB <= w;
                              tensB <= onesB;
                             B <= {negB,thousandsB,hundredsB,tensB,onesB};
                              end    

                                else if (w == 4'b1111)
                                  begin                           
                                       negB <= ~negB;
                                   if (neg == 1)                                                                                        
                                        tensB <= sign ;
                                         end
                                 else if (( w >= add )&&( w <= div) &&( error == 1'b0))
                                    begin
                                       operand <= w; A <= answer;                    
                                             end 

                                     else if (( w >= add )&&( w <= div) &&( error == 1'b1))     
                                            errordisp <= 1'b1;

                                      else if (( w == enter)&&( error == 1'b0))       
                                                    begin
                                                 A <= answer; operand <= w;
                                                     end

                                             else if (( w == enter)&&( error == 1'b1)) 

                                                   errordisp <= 1'b1;           
     S9:
                  if (( w >= 0)&&( w <= 9))
                                begin 
                                  neg <= sign;
                                  thousandsB <= hundredsB;
                                  hundreds <= tensB;
                                  onesB <= w;
                                 tensB <= onesB;
                                B <= {negB,thousandsB,hundredsB,tensB,onesB};
                                end
               else if (( w >= add )&&( w <= div)&&( error == 1'b0))
                       begin 
                       A <= answer;
                       operand <= w;
                       end

               else if (w == 4'b1111)
                       negB <= ~negB;

               else if    (( w >= add )&&( w <= div)&&( error == 1'b1))   
                        errordisp <= 1'b1;

               else if ((w == enter)&&( error == 1'b0))             
                        A <= answer;

               else if ((w == enter)&&( error == 1'b1))
                      errordisp <= 1'b1; 

       S10:
           if (( w >= 10 )&&( w <= div)) 
               operand <= w;

           else if (( w >= 0) && (w <= 9)&&(error == 1'b0))
               begin
               A <= {1'b0,4'b0,4'b0,4'b0,ones};
                   ones <= w;

                   end
            else if (w == 4'b1111) 
                  neg <= ~neg;        


          default: 
          A <= {1'b0,4'b0,4'b0,4'b0,4'b0}; 
          endcase

always@(*)
if  (operand == 4'b1010)
   Operator = 2'b00;
else if (operand == 4'b1011)
Operator = 2'b01;
else if (operand == 4'b1100)
Operator = 2'b10;
else if (operand == 4'b1101)
Operator = 2'b11;
else 
Operator = 2'b00;


//BCDtosigned A1(.BCD(A),.sign2(A2),.negA(neg),.onesA(ones),.tensA(tens),.hundredsA(hundreds),.thousandsA(thousands));
//BCDtosigned B1(.BCD(B),.sign2(B2),.negA(negB),.onesA(onesB),.tensA(tensB),.hundredsA(hundredsB),.thousandsA(thousandsB));
//arithmetic M1(.X(A2),.Y(B2),.Zout(Z1),.Operator(Operator),.Error(error));
//signedtoBCD C1(.BCDG(answer),.sign2(Z1));

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the multi-driven error means that you are making assignments to the same `reg` from 2 different `always` blocks.

For example, the `ones` `reg` is assigned in the block `// OUTPUT LOGIC`:

```
                        {neg,thousands,hundreds,tens,ones} =  {blk,blk,blk,blk,4'b0};
```

and also in the block `// REGISTER TRANFER OPERATIONS`, starting with:

```
        ones <= 4'b0;
```

I was able to easily figure this out because I read your code into a source code browser tool which has the intelligence to show me a short list of all the lines where `ones` is driven (assigned).

If the tool you use does not have this capability, then you can search in your editor for all lines of code where `ones` is on the left-hand side of an assignment.

You should only make assignments to the same `reg` from a single `always` blocks.  You need to redesign your code, as you already suspected.

---

There are several other basic Verilog issues with your code, but complete code reviews are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Refer to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).